# ios swift uitableview add last cell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I want to add a cell into my tableview to the last row using another UserInterface.The code is like this.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:JoinCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! JoinCell

    let lastSectionIndex = tableView.numberOfSections-1
    let lastSectionLastRow = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(lastSectionIndex) - 1
    let lastIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:lastSectionLastRow, inSection: lastSectionIndex)

    let cellIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

    if cellIndexPath == lastIndexPath {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("JoinFooterCell") as! JoinFooterCell
    }
```

I got error message "Cannot assign value of type 'JoinFooterCell' to type 'JoinCell'"

Does anyone can give me advise? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can help us help you by formatting your so we don't have scroll it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this and for `datasource.sections.count` use the same value you return in `numberOfSectionInTableView()` and for `datasource.rows.count` use the same value you return in your `numberOfRowsForSection()`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if datasource.sections.count - 1 == indexPath.section && datasource.rows.count - 1 == indexPath.row {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("JoinFooterCell") as! JoinFooterCell
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! JoinCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
let lastSectionIndex = tableView.numberOfSections-1
let lastSectionLastRow = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(lastSectionIndex) - 1
let lastIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:lastSectionLastRow, inSection: lastSectionIndex)

let cellIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
var cell
if cellIndexPath == lastIndexPath {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("JoinFooterCell") as! JoinFooterCell
}
else {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! JoinCell
}
```

What actually am trying to do is create cell which you want to return. Don't initialize the cell first and then try to re assign. First determine whether its the last cell and based on that, initialize the kind of cell you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. I can't get the indexPathForCell after declare cell.

Answer (score 0):

Let try this:

```
var cell: UITableViewCell!
if cellIndexPath == lastIndexPath {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("JoinFooterCell") as! JoinFooterCell
} else {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! JoinCell
}
return cell
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. I can't get the indexPathForCell because cell is nothing.